# Convert a string column in a NumPy record array to uppercase

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, recarray

I create a numpy record array (recarray) as follows:

```
import numpy as np
recs = [('Bill', '31', 260.0), ('Fred', 15, '145.0')]
r = np.rec.fromrecords(recs, names = 'name, age, weight')
```

Now I want to alter the column `r['name']` so that the values are in uppercase. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
recs = [('Bill', '31', 260.0), ('Fred', 15, '145.0')]
r = np.rec.fromrecords(recs, names = 'name, age, weight')
r['name'] = np.char.upper(r['name'])
r
rec.array([('BILL', '31', '260.0'), ('FRED', '15', '145.0')],
          dtype=[('name', '<U4'), ('age', '<U2'), ('weight', '<U32')])
```

np.char is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a more general function, such as ```apply``` for pandas series?

Comment: like the Addendum? to my response

Comment: `pandas.apply` just  iterates over the dataframe rows.  Nothing fancier than a list comprehension.

Comment: And how would you iterate over and update each element in a column of a recarray?

Comment: The column has changed.  Is your question changing to how do you convert every column to uppercase?

Comment: No, I just changed the headline to better reflect the question.

Comment: @Nan, I accepted your answer, it answers my question perfectly. I deleted the addendum, as it didn't answer my poorly written comment question. I will reformulate that question and make a separate question for that one